# What's the deal with vertical-align: baseline?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, baseline

I thought I knew my way around CSS, but I needed to explain something to someone just now and I found I couldn't.

My question basically boils down to: why is `vertical-align:baseline` ignored when there are other alignments in the same line?

Example: if the second span has `vertical-align:bottom`, the first span's vertical alignment is ignored if it is `baseline`; it behaves as if it has `bottom` too.

```css
span:first-child {vertical-align:baseline}
span:last-child {font-size:3em; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>one</span> <span>two</span>
</p>
```

While if all the spans have a vertical-align other than `baseline`, or, if they are all `baseline`, then they behave as expected.

```css
span:first-child {vertical-align:top}
span:last-child {font-size:3em; vertical-align:bottom;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>one</span> <span>two</span>
</p>
```

```css
span:first-child {vertical-align:baseline}
span:last-child {font-size:3em; vertical-align:baseline;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>one</span> <span>two</span>
</p>
```

If this is normal behaviour, then why isn't it described anywhere? I haven't found any source that says baseline and top/bottom interfere with each other in such a way.

Comment: In a single sentence: the presence of differently-aligned inlines does not alter the baseline of the current line.

Comment: @BoltClock Then where IS the baseline of the current line in my example? Call me dense, but I still don't understand. Why does the first span jump up and down if you change the vertical-alignment of the second one to `top` or `middle` or `bottom`? What am I missing?

Comment: @MrLister - the position of the baseline of the current line is irrelevant. It's where the baseline of the first span is, and where the baseline of the strut is, but it plays no part in the relative positions of the two spans nor in their positions within the line box. CSS 2.2 section 10.8 point 2 is in effect here "If such boxes are tall enough, there are multiple solutions and CSS 2.2 does not define the position of the line box's baseline". Browsers do something sane, but it's not really defined by CSS.

Comment: @Alohci That makes sense; I'll have to do some testing based on it. But so far, I haven't found any situation where the browsers behave differently, so if this really is not governed by any formal definition, they're remarkably coherent here! (I mean, in most other cases where the formal definition is too vague, the browsers will find a way to differ in how they do it.)

Comment: For a browser difference, try this variant of Paolo Forgia's last example: In https://jsfiddle.net/Lotfg2L7/ I've just reversed the heights of the second and third spans. Compare the vertical position of the first span in Firefox, with where it appears in Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 63):

## Vertical-Align

[`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is used to align [inline-level elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-level). These are elements, whose [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property evaluates to:

- `inline`
- `inline-block`
- `inline-table` (not considered in this answer)

Inline-level elements are laid out next to each other in lines. Once there are more elements than fit into the current line, a new line is created beneath it. All these lines have a so-called **line box**, which encloses all the content of its line. Differently sized content means line boxes of different height.

*In the following illustration the top and bottom of line boxes are indicated by red lines.*
[image]

Inside these line boxes the property `vertical-align` is responsible for aligning the individual elements.

## Baseline

The most important reference point to align vertically is the baseline of the involved elements. In some cases the top and bottom edge of the element’s enclosing box becomes important, too.

#### Inline elements

[image]

The top and bottom edge of the line height is indicated by red lines, the height of the font by green lines and the baseline by a blue line.

**On the left**, the text has a line height set to the same height as the font-size. The green and red line collapsed to one line on each side.

**In the middle**, the line height is twice as large as the font-size.

**On the right**, the line height is half as large as the font-size.

Note that the inline element’s outer edges (the red lines) does not matter, if the line height is smaller than the height of the font.

#### Inline-Block Element

[image]

**From left to right** you see:

- an `inline-block` element with [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content
- an `inline-block` element with [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content and `overflow: hidden`
- an `inline-block` element with no [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content (but the content area has a height)

The boundaries of the margin is indicated by red lines, the border is yellow, the padding green and the content area blue. The baseline of each `inline-block` element is shown as a blue line.

The `inline-block` element’s baseline depends on whether the element has [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content. In case of:

- [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content the baseline of the `inline-block` element is the baseline of the last content element in normal flow (*example on the left*)
- [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content but an `overflow` property evaluating to something other than visible, the baseline is the bottom edge of the margin-box (*example in the middle*)
- no [in-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#positioning-scheme) content the baseline is, again, the bottom edge of the margin-box (*example on the right*)

#### Line box

[image]

This is probably the most confusing part, when working with `vertical-align`. It means, the baseline is placed where ever it needs to be to fulfil all other conditions like `vertical-align` and **minimizing** the line box’s height. It is a **free parameter** in the equation.

Since the line box’s baseline is invisible, it may not immediately be obvious where it is. But, you can make it visible very easily. Just add a character at the beginning of the line in questions, like the "x" in the figure. If this character is not aligned in any way, it will sit on the baseline by default.

Around its baseline the line box has what we might call its text box (green lines in the figure). The text box can simply be thought of as an inline element inside the line box without any alignment. Its height is equal to the `font-size` of its parent element. Therefore, the text box only just encloses the unformatted text of the line box. Since this text box is tied to the baseline, it moves when the baseline moves.

## Snippet

If you want to do some experiment with various `vertical-align` and `font-size` here you have a snippet where you can try it out. Is also available in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcp47hm4/6/).

```js
let sl1 = document.getElementById('sl1');
let sl2 = document.getElementById('sl2');
let sl3 = document.getElementById('sl3');
let sl4 = document.getElementById('sl4');
let elm1 = document.getElementById('elm1');
let elm2 = document.getElementById('elm2');
let elm3 = document.getElementById('elm3');
let elm4 = document.getElementById('elm4');
let ip1 = document.getElementById('ip1');
let ip2 = document.getElementById('ip2');
let ip3 = document.getElementById('ip3');
let ip4 = document.getElementById('ip4');
let slArr = [sl1, sl2, sl3, sl4];
let elmArr = [elm1, elm2, elm3, elm4];
let ipArr = [ip1, ip2, ip3, ip4];
let valueArr = ['baseline', 'top', 'middle', 'bottom'];
for (let i = 0; i < slArr.length; i++) {
  slArr[i].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    elmArr[i].style.verticalAlign = event.target.value;
    elmArr[i].innerHTML = event.target.value;
    addDiv();
  })
}
for (let i = 0; i < ipArr.length; i++) {
  ipArr[i].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    elmArr[i].style.fontSize = event.target.value + 'em';
    addDiv();
  })
}

document.getElementById('btnRandom').addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < elmArr.length; i++) {
    let element = elmArr[i];
    let fontSize = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    ipArr[i].value = fontSize;
    element.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'em';
    let styleIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    element.style.verticalAlign = valueArr[styleIndex];
    element.innerHTML = valueArr[styleIndex];
    slArr[i].selectedIndex = styleIndex;
  }
}, this);

function addDiv() {
  let view = document.getElementById('viewer');
  view.innerHTML = "";
  elmArr.forEach(function(element) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.appendChild(element.cloneNode());
    view.appendChild(div);
  }, this);
}
```

```css
.header span {
  color: #000;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
}

#elms {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 1em;
}

#elm1 {
  background-color: #300;
}

#elm2 {
  background-color: #6B0;
}

#elm3 {
  background-color: #90A;
}

#elm4 {
  background-color: #B00;
}

div {
  z-index: -1;
}

#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 25%;
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
}

#div3 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 75%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"> <span style="width: 100px;display: block;float: left;margin-right: 20px;">vertical align</span> <span>font-size(em)</span> </div>
<div>

  <select name="sl1" id="sl1">
    <option value="baseline">baseline</option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="middle">middle</option>
    <option value="bottom">bottom</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="ip1" />
  <br>
  <select name="sl2" id="sl2">
    <option value="baseline">baseline</option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="middle">middle</option>
    <option value="bottom">bottom</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="ip2" />
  <br>
  <select name="sl3" id="sl3">
    <option value="baseline">baseline</option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="middle">middle</option>
    <option value="bottom">bottom</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="ip3" />
  <br>
  <select name="sl4" id="sl4">
    <option value="baseline">baseline</option>
    <option value="top">top</option>
    <option value="middle">middle</option>
    <option value="bottom">bottom</option>
  </select>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="ip4" />
  <br>
  <button id="btnRandom" (onclick)="random()">Random</button>
</div>
<div id="elms">
  <span id="elm1">one</span>
  <span id="elm2">two</span>
  <span id="elm3">three</span>
  <span id="elm4">four</span>
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
<div id="viewer"></div>
```

*This snippet is made by [Duannx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4254681/duannx).*

---

<sub>**Source:** Please note that this is an extract of [Vertical-Align: All You Need To Know](http://christopheraue.net/2014/03/05/vertical-align/) written by Christopher Aue.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

The question is why are `vertical-align: baseline;` ignored. Well I don't think it is. In your first snippet you're using `baseline` and `bottom` what clearly gives a difference between the two `<span>` elements. So what does `baseline` do? Well `baseline` Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of the parent element. In the example below I've copied and adjusted some parts to give the difference.

```css
span.one {vertical-align:baseline}
span.two {vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="one">one</span> <span class="two">two</span>
</p>
```

As you can see the `baseline` alignment acts normal just as the `middle` alignment.

Now lets test something else. lets swap the alignment of `baseline` and `middle` and edit `middle` and add a third `<span>`

```css
span.one { vertical-align: top;}
span.two { vertical-align: baseline;}

span.three {vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; }
p {
height: 50px;
background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="one">one</span> <span class="two">two</span> <span class="two">two</span><br><br> <span class="three">three</span>
</p>
```

Now if you'll edit the second snippet and take a look at the `vertical-align` of `<span class="three">` you can clearly see that when changing the alignment the text does change it's position.

But you're question relates on text on the same line so lets take a look at the snippet down below.

```css
span.one { vertical-align: middle;}
span.two { vertical-align: baseline;}

span.three {vertical-align: middle; height: 20px; }
p {
height: 50px;
background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="one">one</span> <span class="two">two</span> <span class="two">two</span><span class="three">three</span>
</p>
```

As you can see in this third snippet I've placed the third `<span>` next to one and two. And it does make a difference. The `baseline` in this case is different from the `middle` alignment. This is because the `baseline` grabs the `baseline` of the parent. since the parent's height is normal it doesn't affect `baseline` and `top` alignment. but when you'll use `middle` or `sub` it is clearly a difference.

For information about each alignment, check out this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp).

Answer (score 1):

A shorter explanation: A starting point is knowing where the baseline of the parent is. Add some text within the `<p>` tag or a `<span>` with `vertical-alignment` set to `baseline` (span "one" below). The baseline of span "one" is the bottom of the characters, e.g. the bottom of the letter 'n'.

Then its easy to see how the other spans change in relation to it. I added a border around span "one" so we can see its top and bottom edges clearly.

```css
span {  }
span:nth-child(1) {vertical-align:baseline; font-size:3em; border: 1px solid gray}
span:nth-child(2) {vertical-align:top; color:red}
span:nth-child(3) {vertical-align:middle; color:green;}
span:nth-child(4) {vertical-align:bottom; color:blue;}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>one</span> <span>two</span> <span>three</span> <span>four</span>
</p>
```