# What does parent box mean for vertical-align?

Tags: html, css

My question focus on the parent box of vertical-aligned elements,it is totally different from the post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996242/whats-the-deal-with-vertical-align-baseline`,the description in w3c is obscure for the concept `parent box`.
In the manual w3c .
[definition on vertical-align](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html)
baseline
    Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If the box doesn't have a baseline, align the bottom of the box with the parent's baseline.

Let's take a real simple example.

```css
.parent{width:200px;height:100px;border:1px solid red;}
.foo {
  vertical-align: baseline;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: plum;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <span>the quick brown fox</span>
    <div class="foo">
    </div>
    <span>jump over the lazy dog.</span>
</div>
```

What is the div.foo's parent box?
It is div.parent?
How to line out all the attributions:baseline,sub,super,text-top,text-bottom,top,bottom,middle for div.parent such as below?

[image]

I found some contradictions here.
All the vertical-align attributions:baseline,sub,super,text-top,text-bottom,top,bottom,middle applied to inline-level and table-cell elements.

div.parent is a block box,no such concepts as baseline,sub,super,text-top,text-bottom,top,bottom,middle for it.

Then how to say Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box?
The parent box has no baseline attribution at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the deal with vertical-align: baseline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996242/whats-the-deal-with-vertical-align-baseline)