# Empty string in array of *ngFor causes strange placement issues (as opposed to non-empty strings in the array)

Tags: angular

A live demo link speaks a thousand words: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5vwspd

As you can see, the first 2 days are places awkwardly.

---

I'm creating a calendar component, and to display the day numbers (eg 1,2,...,31) I have a `days` array. But in order for the `1` to appear under the right weekday (eg Tu) I need to pad `days` with empty strings.

However, these empty strings are causing strange placement issues. The elements of the empty string are placed higher than the others.

For example, in my `.ts` file:
`days = ['','','',...,'30','31'];`

In my `.html` file:

```
<li *ngFor="let day of days">
    <div class="dayNumber">
       {{day}}
    </div>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The defaut vertical alignment of the `div` elements is `vertical-align: baseline`. The baseline is based on the text content (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43996242/1009922)) but, when the element is empty, it appears to be at the bottom of the element.

You can avoid the problem by displaying a non-breakable space when a string is empty or contains only spaces:

```
{{ day.trim() || '&nbsp;' }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lwdkqn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for a demo.

---

As an alternative, you can specify the vertical alignment for the `.days li` elements. Any alignment value will do except `baseline`, which is the default that causes the problem.

```
.days li {
  ...
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lgredz?file=src/app/app.component.css) for a demo. Thanks to [codequiet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10730815/codequiet) for the suggestion.

Comment: But what even causes the problem? Why is the div without content higher up?

Comment: It is actually the elements with numbers displayed which are oriented *lower* than the elements with no content inside.

Comment: You could also use a zero-width space (`&#8203;`) in place of the non-breaking space. This would essentially render as an empty element.

Comment: You can also just add `vertical-align: middle;` to the '.days li' rule

Comment: Thanks a lot! codequiet's solution is slightly better because his does not leave an empty string in the webpage which can be "seen" when highlighting.