# After adding display: block, the content of the nav item increases to 1px, which causes the parent item's height

Tags: css, flexbox, display

The following figure points to the current UI:

[image: Initial UI]|

The given HTML and CSS code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Flexbox example page</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul class="site-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="nav-right"><a href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: unset;
  background-color: #709b90;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.site-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #5f4b44;
}
.site-nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #cc6b5a;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

The original problem arises after applying the following CSS:

```css
.site-nav > li > a {
  display: block;
}
```

The resulting UI:

[image: Resulted UI]

***The resulting UI is expected for me, but I can't figure out how the CSS works here.***

**NOTE**  I tried dev tooling, and it appears that the `block` value causes the element to take the entire width of its parent, introducing a line break. This increases the height of the nav item's content to `1px`.

Now, my concern is,

1. How does the `display: block` property affect the UI? (i.e. After adding the `block` value, the padding of the `li` element increases automatically!)
2. What's the underlying idea here that I couldn't figure out?
3. Is there any deep understanding that I'm missing?

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: I am reading your question as "why does `display: inline` behave differently from `display: block`, technically?"; is that your question? Also, you are talking about some "original problem" (your current UI?); about "resulting UI" and "expected" outcome, but never stating what your _desired_ outcome is. What is exactly is your problem? What is your desired outcome? On what do you seek clarification?

Comment: @OskarGrosser, I'm trying to get the key idea of _why the UI is changing just for converting the `inline` to `block`_. I believe you noticed that the height of the `li` element increased.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: *Only inline-axis sizes are respected* for inline boxes in inline formatting contexts; block-axis sizes are ignored.

---

[CSS Display 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/) includes an [informative table for `display`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#display-value-summary), where it lists:

| Short `display` | Full `display` | Generated box |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `inline` | `inline flow` | inline box |

Such an [inline box](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#inline-box) is defined as:

> A non-replaced [inline-level](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#inline-level) box
> whose [inner display type](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#inner-display-type) is ['flow'](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#valdef-display-flow).
> The contents of an inline box participate
> in the same inline formatting context as the inline box itself.

Where ['flow'](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#valdef-display-flow) is defined as:

> The element lays out its contents
> using ***flow layout*** ([block-and-inline layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html)).
>
> If its [outer display type](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display/#outer-display-type) is 'inline' ...,
> and it is participating in a block or inline formatting context,
> then it generates an inline box.
>
> ...

The linked "block-and-inline layout" definition is a bit outdated, but it reads (in *9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts* of CSS 2.1):

> Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes.

A more up-to-date resource would be [*2. Inline Layout Model* of CSS Inline 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#inline-formatting-context), though it basically states the same:

> In an [inline formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-inline-3/#inline-formatting-context), content is laid out
> along the [inline axis](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-4/#inline-axis), ... . Inline-axis margins, borders, and padding
> are respected between inline-level boxes ... .

This effectively means that **block-axis sizes are ignored** in these cases.

Example:

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: both;
}

span {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  padding-block: .8em;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>Try</span> resizing the <code>&lt;p&gt;</code> element!
  <span>This</span> is some inline-level content
  with several <code>&lt;span&gt;</code>s <span>throughout</span>,
  to see their block-axis sizes being <span>ignored</span>.
</p>
```

By changing from `inline` to `block`, the block-axis margins, borders and paddings will be respected as well: The `a` elements will push out the block-axis size of the ancestor `.site-nav`, instead of overlapping the ancestor's padding.

---

I believe the extra `1px` at the bottom comes `vertical-align` being `baseline` by default, incidentally overlapping the top. (Read [more about `vertical-align` in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43996861/13561410).)

Example comparing `vertical-align: baseline` and `middle`:

```css
div {
  padding-block: .5em;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

span {
  padding-block: .5em;
  background-color: lightpink;
}

#inline-middle span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#block span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<figure id="inline">
  <div>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <caption><code>&lt;div&gt;</code> with inline-level <code>&lt;span&gt;</code></caption>
</figure>

<figure id="inline-middle">
  <div>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <caption>
    <code>&lt;div&gt;</code> with inline-level <code>&lt;span&gt;</code> aligned to middle
  </caption>
</figure>

<figure id="block">
  <div>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
  <caption><code>&lt;div&gt;</code> with block-level <code>&lt;span&gt;</code></caption>
</figure>
```

Comment: On mobile, `vertical-align: baseline` has no "1px", but `middle` has at the top. Someone with more knowledge about `vertical-align` may clear up the "1px" thing, but certainly isn't me.

Answer (score 0):

### display: block vs. inline

In the snippet I created below, I think you'll get a better picture of what is happening when you add `display: block;`. I have added inline styling to only a few of the `<a>` tags to better illustrate the difference between the `display: block;` and the default `display: inline;`.

The first, third and fifth `<a>` tags are showing the `display: block;` behaviour, which is to take up the space they occupy as though they have rigid containers.

The second and fourth `<a>` tags are showing the `display: inline;` behaviour, which is that they don't take up an entire space, but rather, live within the space they have been placed within.

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: unset;
  background-color: #709b90;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.site-nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #5f4b44;
}
.site-nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #cc6b5a;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Flexbox example page</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul class="site-nav">
        <li><a style="display: block;" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><a style="display: block;" href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li class="nav-right"><a style="display: block;" href="#">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think this summary generally answers all three of your questions, but let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: It demonstrates the issue but does not really explain it... the OP already knows it happens, they want to know WHY.

Comment: I stated pretty clearly why this happens. display: inline is the default for a tags and by changing to display: block, the structure of the a tags with their parent containers is altered.

Comment: so the reason why when using display:block the padding of the container is showing up is because when you use display:block the padding of the container is showing up.. it's a very clear explanation isn't it?